# Python, for in behind some function, what is it?

Tags: python, pyaudio, google-speech-api

I'm trying to understand google speech to text sample, it takes data from micro and convert the audio to text

Whole source code is here
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/microphone/transcribe_streaming_mic.py#L181

generator will yield some data

```
  def generator(self):
        while not self.closed:
            #.....
            yield b''.join(data)
```

```
audio_generator = stream.generator()
requests = (types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content)
                    for content in audio_generator)
responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)
listen_print_loop(responses)
```

I only know little about python, cannot understand above code, seems generator will not block if some data is yield.

What does the `for .. in` line mean?

If the audio data comes for ever the `for loop` will run forever? and when will `client.streaming_recognize` gets run?

===UPDATE

OK, now I know generator..

but still does not understand for in line, does it mean:

```
for content in audio_generator:
    requests = types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content)
```

?

Comment: Most of your question is answered by [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1756096/364696). The rest seems to be stumbling about caused by not understanding generators/generator expressions, so learning about them should answer your other questions.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks, how about the for in line?

Comment: It's a generator expression. Think lazy list comprehension. This is also covered by the duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Is `requests` a tuple? because it's inside a parentheses. so every yield will call `types.StreamingRecognizeRequest` and return a value, so requests is  a tuple?

Comment: No. Read the top answer to the duplicate, it describes *exactly* what that does. You're guessing without reading. For the record, `tuple`s are not defined by the presence of parentheses (`x = 1, 2` makes a `tuple`) outside of the empty `tuple` (which does need them), you just need the parentheses in some cases to force proper grouping.

Comment: I have read. I understand that for will call next() automatically. so `content` will be the yield data. I still cannot understand `for in` line here(a function before `for in`),

Comment: I see. requests is also a generator?? and client.streaming_recognize use generator as argument?

Comment: [membership operator, `in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations)